# Bidirectional OneToMany / ManyToOne doesn't work

Tags: jpa

my problem is that adding a collection of parent entities to a child doesn't set the foreign keys on the owning side. Can anybody give me hints? What am I doing wrong here?

```
// Entity Class: Paket
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "paket", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Komponente.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Komponente> komponenten;

    public void setKomponenten(List<Komponente> komponenten) {
        this.komponenten = komponenten;
    }

    public List<Komponente> getKomponenten() {
        return komponenten;
    }

// Entity Class: Komponente
@ManyToOne()
private Paket paket;

// Using EJB -> Excerpt from abstract service class
@Transactional
    public T edit(T entity) throws OptimisticLockException {
        try {
            T myEntity = getEntityManager().merge(entity);
            getEntityManager().flush();
            return myEntity;
        } catch (OptimisticLockException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }

        //System.out.println("Entity Merged: " + entity);
    }

// Performing merge
Paket p = this.paketFacade.find(new Long(1));
p.setKomponenten(komponenteInSelectedPaketList);
this.selectedPaket = this.paketFacade.edit(p);
```

Comment: set the Paket of the komponent. Otherwise the owning side isn't set, which for Hibernate, means that the association doesn't exist.

Comment: @JB Nizet Do I need to iterate over each Komponente entity and set the paket?

Comment: Yes, you must do that

Comment: @JB Nizet I just realized that. Thank you very much.